# Simulate creation of multiple files in C# via unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, file

This is more of a gimmick, as I would like to achieve full coverage with my unit tests.

And this is about a `FileFinder()` method.
This method looks for files in a folder and creates a corresponding incremental naming.

Now I was given that it should be possible (for whatever reason) that 999,998 files may be in this folder.

If accordingly it is detected that there is a file called for example `Job_999999.something`, then this should return an **empty string**.

The corresponding code snippet looks like this:

```
var allFiles = new List<string>();
allFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(SomeImagesPath));
allFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(TempFolderPathForSomething));

var allExistingFiles = allFiles.Select(x =>
                                              {
                                                 var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x);
                                                 return fileNameWithoutExtension.TrimStart('V', 'v').TrimStart('S', 's', 'P', 'p', 'V', 'v', 'I', 'i');
                                              })
                                      .ToList();
                                      
var i = 0;
while (i < 1000000)
{
   i++;
   if (!allExistingFiles.Contains($"{i:000000}"))
      break;
   if (i == 999999)
      return string.Empty;
}
```

I covered everything via unit tests, only the if case was not possible for me.

Personally, I consider this rather pointless as well, however I was wondering (without naming to you the functionality before and after) if there is a way to simulate via a unit test that 1 million files are created? And if it is possible, do I have to write some kind of TearDown method that rudders everything back or is there no such possibility in the first place?

Or is there generally a way to "trick" this code point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, your method is hardcoded to use System.IO.Directory. This means that you must code against an actual file system. That means when you go to unit test it, it would hit the actual file system. That's not ideal. A unit test should not have external dependencies.

We can fix this situation by coding against an abstraction. The [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions) library provides prebuilt abstractions and concrete implementations for us already. That allows us to choose when we want to work with the real file system (during normal runtime) and when we want to work with a mock of the file system (during unit testing).

```
readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;

// I'm assuming you use Dependency Injection.
// To hit the real system, your app should inject a System.IO.Abstractions.FileSystem.
// To test, you can pass in a System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers.MockFileSystem
public MyClass(IFileSystem fileSystem)
{
    _fileSystem = fileSystem;
}

public string FileFinder()
{
    var allFiles = new List<string>();
    allFiles.AddRange(_fileSystem.Directory.GetFiles(SomeImagesPath));
    allFiles.AddRange(_fileSystem.Directory.GetFiles(TempFolderPathForSomething));

    var allExistingFiles = allFiles.Select(x =>
                                                  {
                                                     var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x);
                                                     return fileNameWithoutExtension.TrimStart('V', 'v').TrimStart('S', 's', 'P', 'p', 'V', 'v', 'I', 'i');
                                                  })
                                          .ToList();
                                          
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000)
    {
       i++;
       if (!allExistingFiles.Contains($"{i:000000}"))
          break;
       if (i == 999999)
          return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Your test then becomes:

```
[UnitTest]
public void MyTest()
{
    //arrange
    var mockFileSystem = new System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers.MockFileSystem();
    //add fake files as needed to mockFileSystem
    var myClass = new MyClass(mockFileSystem);
    
    //act
    string result = myClass.FileFinder();
    
    //assert
    //make assertions here about your result
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `allExistingFiles` list creation to a method, which returns `List<string>`, then you need only to mock it and return different lists for your test scenarios - a list that contains `Job_999999.something`, a list without it, etc.
Adding some kind of mechanism to produce these in unit test flow makes it an integration test, not a unit test, as it breaks the idea of testing a unit of code.
Everything that connects your application with the external API (file system, database, etc) isn't a subject of unit test. (you can still automate its testing if you want, but it's a different topic).